# xslt Adding attribute to xml root node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I have a XML:

```
<doc>
   <tag1>
      <tag11>1</tag11>
      <tag12>abc</tag12>
      <tag13>test</tag13>
      <tag14>content</tag14>
      <tag15>2-</tag15>
      <tag16>content</tag16>
      <tag17>
         <tag171>TITLE</tag171>
         <tag172>T3</tag172>
         <tag173>No</tag173>
      <tag17>
      <tag18 id="t/9905">aaa</tag18>
      <tag18 id="t/9905">bbb</tag18>
   </tag1>
   <tag2>
      <tag21>2016</tag21>
      <tag22>
         <tag221>1</tag221>
         <tag222>OMG</tag222>
      </tag22>
      <tag23>
         <tag231>Test</tag231>
         <tag232>2016-01-18T00:00:00</tag232>
         <tag233>This is a test</tag233>
      </tag23>
   </tag2>
</doc>
```

I want to add an attribute (namespace) to the root element: /doc such that the output would look like:

```
<doc xmlns="urn:test">
   <tag1>
      <tag11>
         <othertags />
      </tag11>
   </tag1>
   <tag2>
      <tag21>
         <othertags2 />
      </tag21>
   </tag2>
</doc>
```

I've tried three xslt (skipped the default copy all part to reduce length of the question).

xslt1: see below, the problem is that empty namespace xmlns="" is added to all sub-node of /doc (i.e.: /doc/tag1 and /doc/tag2)

```
<xsl:template match="/doc">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:test" >
      <xsl:copy-of select="attribute::*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Xslt2: see below, the problem is that "ns" is added to root node:  and

```
<xsl:template match="/*"> 
   <xsl:element name="ns:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:test"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /> 
   </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
```

xslt3: see below, the problem is that error reported: Undefined namespace prefix 'urn'. XPST0081: A namespace prefix used in an expression must be expandable into a namespace URI using the statically known namespaces.

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="xmlns">
         <xsl:value-of select="urn:test" />
      </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
   <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I just want a simple output with xmlns="urn:test" with the root node /doc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add an attribute (namespace) to the root element

A namespace declaration is **not** an attribute. And the change required here is not to the root element alone: the namespace declared at root is inherited by all its descendants. That means you need to move **all** elements into the new namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:test">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Michael, Thanks for the answer. The xslt your provided has same output as my first xslt. I really don't want to have the "xmlns=""" on all sub-nodes. Is there a way to remove it on sub-nodes with a 2nd xslt?

Comment: @dellair The output of my XSLT does **not** have "xmlns=""" on all sub-nodes - see: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifq3

Comment: This is absolutely my bad. I just edited the question and had the full xml copied. You can see that "xmlns=""" has been added to sub-nodes with the full xml.

Comment: Your new XML is not well-formed. If I correct that, I still don't see any nodes with "xmlns=""" - see: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifq3/1

Comment: Michael, you couldn't be more right. My issue was I used the "/*" in the match pattern instead of "*". Cheers!